# How to make animation happen when you click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, gsap

I'm new to jQuery and JavaScript, don't judge strictly.
I wrote a small script to animate the display of tabs. And I decided to add animation when hovering and clicking on the button itself. But I can't figure out how to do it. Made an animation when hovering through mouseenter and mouseleave. I want these lines to move to the center of the word when you click them, and when you click another button in active mode, they leave the old one and appear on the new one.

```
$buttons.click(function() {
  var selected = $(this).index();
  TweenMax.to($buttons, 1, {x: -500, opacity: 0.25});
  TweenMax.to(this, 0.5, {opacity: 1, color: '#85729E'});

  TweenMax.to($tabs, 0.5, {x: 0, opacity: 0, display:'none', delay: 0.5 });
  TweenMax.to($tabs.eq(selected), 1, { opacity: 1, display:'block', delay: 0.5 });
});
```

I uploaded the full code to [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nikita-sidorenko/pen/abdMzPO)

Comment: This has already been answered over [on the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/24920-how-to-make-animation-happen-when-you-click/?tab=comments#comment-119641).

Comment: @ZachSaucier, I created the question, I'm really confused

Answer (score -1):

In your html code use the `onclick` attribute with the function as the value.

Example:

```
<button type='button' onclick='functionOnClick()'>Click me</button>
```

```
function functionOnClick() {
// Execute functionality here
}
```

EDIT:

Better answer

```
buttonId.addEventListener('click', functionOnClick());
```